# How to check particular SQL UserID windows permissions in MS SQL SERVER 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions, sql-server-agent, windows-server

I would like to say as per my network system administrative security of windows Server 2012 R2. I am unable to start SQL Server agent. As per in MS SQL Server 2012 , i have "sysadmin" & "public"  privilege.
As per microsoft documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178130(v=sql.110).aspx) those who have below mention windows credential then he/she will be able to run SQL Server agent.

Security

Permissions

To perform its functions, SQL Server Agent must be configured to use the credentials of an account that is a member of the sysadmin fixed server role in SQL Server. The account must have the following Windows permissions:

•
Log on as a service (SeServiceLogonRight)

•
Replace a process-level token (SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege)

•
Bypass traverse checking (SeChangeNotifyPrivilege)

•
Adjust memory quotas for a process (SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege)

How to check particular SQL UserID windows permissions in MS SQL SERVER 2012 , to avail all the feasibility of "SQL Server agent" services.

Comment: You can alter these settings in the [Local Security Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739424(v=ws.10).aspx) window.

Comment: @John . "Local Security Policy" Group policy access denied to my account.

Comment: @John I don't Have Windows Server 2012 R2 GPO permission , i have only Database permission in my environment

Comment: That's where you can check / modify the settings. You need to find someone with access.